# How do I reorder a factor

Tags: r

I want to reorder a factor based on one of its rows. For example I want to reorder the "country" factor based on the value corresponding to the 2014 entries below. UK would be ranked first and USA second.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  country=c("USA","USA","UK","UK"),
  year=c(2014,2013,2014,2013),
  value=c(2,NA,1,NA)
)    

  country year value
1     USA 2014     2
2     USA 2013    NA
3      UK 2014     1
4      UK 2013    NA
```

I don't quite understand how factors are reordered. It seems the `reorder` command replaces the an entire column in a `data.frame` but it I would think that I should only need to specify a new order for the `factor` labels. "level" seems to do the opposite, giving labels to the ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
factor(dat$country, levels=with(dat[dat$year==2014,], country[order(value)] ))
#[1] USA USA UK  UK 
#Levels: UK USA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
factor(country<-c("USA","USA","UK","UK"),level <- c("UK","USA"))
sort(country)
```